# How to write a double back button pressed to exit app using flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter, and I saw many android apps can exit when double press back button.

The first time press back button, app shows a toast"press again to exit app".
The following second press, app exits.
Of course, the time between two press must be not long.

How to do it in flutter?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This is an example of my code (I've used "fluttertoast" for showing toast message, you can use snackbar or alert or anything else)

```
DateTime currentBackPressTime;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: WillPopScope(child: getBody(), onWillPop: onWillPop),
  );
}

Future<bool> onWillPop() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null || 
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: exit_warning);
      return Future.value(false);
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  }
```

Comment: can you explain what is get body ?

Comment: Just separate method for building my content

Comment: I tried your code but it will back to previous page, not exit the app

Comment: Surely. `WillPopScope` manages only back pressing. So this code can be implemented on first page to prevent unintentionally closing of the app. If you want to close app, you can call `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');` or `SystemNavigator.pop()`

Comment: Thanks for a small and elegant solution!
But I have a problem with this code:
My main `Scaffold` contains a `Drawer`. When the drawer is opened, it normally can be closed with the back button. But now with the drawer opened on the first tap I have a toast with exit_warning and on the second tap the drawer closes. I mean, "press back again to exit" should not affect the drawer. But I cannot figure out how can I solve it.
I use `WillPopScope` as a body of a `Scaffold`, exactly as in the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Answering my own question:
There is `isDrawerOpen` property of `ScaffoldState`, so I should use it.

Comment: `Future<bool> onWillPop() {return ???}` for implement direct back press funtion without dialogue or toast

Comment: the `WillPopScope` is deprecated

Answer (score 31):

You can try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/double_back_to_close_app) package.

Inside a `Scaffold` that wraps all your Widgets, place the `DoubleBackToCloseApp` passing a SnackBar:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DoubleBackToCloseApp(
          child: Home(),
          snackBar: const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Tap back again to leave'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The solution below must be considered deprecated because it causes a few issues that were tackled in the package mentioned. For instance, the app closes if the snack bar was dismissed by the user (see [hcbpassos/double_back_to_close_app#2](https://github.com/hcbpassos/double_back_to_close_app/issues/2)).

### Old answer

You can also opt for a solution involving `SnackBar`. It's not as simple as [Andrey Turkovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7130820/andrey-turkovsky)'s answer, but it's quite more elegant and you won't depend on a library.

```dart
class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  static const snackBarDuration = Duration(seconds: 3);

  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('Press back again to leave'),
    duration: snackBarDuration,
  );

  DateTime backButtonPressTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // The BuildContext must be from one of the Scaffold's children.
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () => handleWillPop(context),
            child: Text('Place your child here'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> handleWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final backButtonHasNotBeenPressedOrSnackBarHasBeenClosed =
        backButtonPressTime == null ||
            now.difference(backButtonPressTime) > snackBarDuration;

    if (backButtonHasNotBeenPressedOrSnackBarHasBeenClosed) {
      backButtonPressTime = now;
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that PopScope prevents the back swipe on ios, with no proper solution from flutter team..

Answer (score 5):

### Migrating from WillPopScope to PopScope

The **WillPopScope** are now deprecated since **Flutter 3.16** because of supporting **Android 14**'s [Predictive back navigation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back). We should migrating from **WillPopScope** to **PopScope**. Below is the modified version of the @Andrii Turkovskyi's answer:

```
DateTime? currentBackPressTime;
bool canPopNow = false;
int requiredSeconds = 2;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: PopScope(
       canPop: canPopNow,
       onPopInvoked: onPopInvoked,
       child: _yourBodyCode(), 
    ),
  );
}

void onPopInvoked(bool didPop) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null || 
        now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: requiredSeconds)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: exit_warning);
      Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: requiredSeconds),
        () {
          // Disable pop invoke and close the toast after 2s timeout
          setState(() {
            canPopNow = false;
          });
          Fluttertoast.cancel();
        },
      );
      // Ok, let user exit app on the next back press
      setState(() {
        canPopNow = true;
      });
  }
```

Comment: It seems that the onPopInvoked method is not being called. Could you please provide more details about the context in which this method should be triggered?  I can't change the canPopNow bool value.

Answer (score 4):

The first time press back button, app shows a AlertDialog"press yes to exit app and press No to can't exit application".
This is an example of my code (I've used 'AlertDialog')

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return new WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
          child: DefaultTabController(
            initialIndex: _selectedIndex,
            length: choices.length,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(

                ),
              ),

          ),
        );
      }
         Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Are you sure?'),
              content: Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('No'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Yes'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ) ?? false;
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately none of them worked for me, I have written one generic class (widget) to handle double tap exit. If someone is interested

```
class DoubleBackToCloseWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child; // Make Sure this child has a Scaffold widget as parent.

  const DoubleBackToCloseWidget({
    @required this.child,
  });

  @override
  _DoubleBackToCloseWidgetState createState() =>
      _DoubleBackToCloseWidgetState();
}

class _DoubleBackToCloseWidgetState extends State<DoubleBackToCloseWidget> {
  int _lastTimeBackButtonWasTapped;
  static const exitTimeInMillis = 2000;

  bool get _isAndroid => Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.android;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isAndroid) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _handleWillPop,
        child: widget.child,
      );
    } else {
      return widget.child;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _handleWillPop() async {
    final _currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    if (_lastTimeBackButtonWasTapped != null &&
        (_currentTime - _lastTimeBackButtonWasTapped) < exitTimeInMillis) {
      Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
      return true;
    } else {
      _lastTimeBackButtonWasTapped = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      Scaffold.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        _getExitSnackBar(context),
      );
      return false;
    }
  }

  SnackBar _getExitSnackBar(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        'Press BACK again to exit!',
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      duration: const Duration(
        seconds: 2,
      ),
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    );
  }
}
```

Use this class following way:

```
class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: DoubleBackToCloseWidget(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text('Hello there'),
                const Text('Hello there again'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is my answer. I used AlertDialog() to achieve this**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Confirm'),
          content: Text('Do you want to exit the App'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('No'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false); //Will not exit the App
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Yes'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true); //Will exit the App
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    ) ?? false;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use double_back_to_close_app library

https://pub.dev/packages/double_back_to_close_app

Add double_back_to_close_app under dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  double_back_to_close_app: ^1.2.0
```

Here example code

```
import 'package:double_back_to_close_app/double_back_to_close_app.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Example());

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DoubleBackToCloseApp(
          snackBar: const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Tap back again to leave'),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: OutlineButton(
              child: const Text('Tap to simulate back'),
              // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
              onPressed: WidgetsBinding.instance.handlePopRoute,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Just move your body contents to "DoubleBackToCloseApp's" child

Answer (score 3):

The best solution without using a package use System

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

or

```
SystemNavigator.pop();
```

Full Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class ExitApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const ExitApp({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExitAppState createState() => _ExitAppState();
}

class _ExitAppState extends State<ExitApp> {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime timeBackPressed = DateTime.now();
    return WillPopScope(
      child: widget.child,
      onWillPop: () async {
        final differeance = DateTime.now().difference(timeBackPressed);
        timeBackPressed = DateTime.now();
        if (differeance >= Duration(seconds: 2)) {
          final String msg = 'Press the back button to exit';
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: msg,
          );
          return false;
        } else {
          Fluttertoast.cancel();
          SystemNavigator.pop();
          return true;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look for time duration between the two consecutive back button clicks, and if the difference is within the desired duration then exit the app.

Here is the complete code sample for the counter app, which exits the app only if the difference between two consecutive back button clicks is less than 1 second (1000 ms)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void showSnackBar() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, right: 32, left: 32),
        content: Text('Tap back button again to exit'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void hideSnackBar() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
  }

  DateTime oldTime = DateTime.now();
  DateTime newTime = DateTime.now();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          newTime = DateTime.now();
          int difference = newTime.difference(oldTime).inMilliseconds;
          oldTime = newTime;
          if (difference < 1000) {
            hideSnackBar();
            return true;
          } else {
            showSnackBar();
            return false;
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_close_app

This is my solution, it is very flexible and simple, does not depend on routing navigation, any page can close the App, such as my login page, and if it is Drawer and PageView, it can also flexibly support custom conditions, and does not need to rely on native method. The following functions are supported:

- ✅ Press back 2 times to close app

  - ✅ Custom time interval
  - ✅ Customize the prompt message
  - ✅ Customize matching conditions
  - ✅ Support Android
- ✅ One click to close app

  - ✅ Support iOS
  - ✅ Support MacOS
  - ✅ Support Windows
  - ✅ Support Linux

Answer (score 2):

Easy to Use and Understand, double tap to exit;
Change the duration to 10000, and short toast message time;

```
 import 'dart:io';
 bool back = false;
 int time = 0;
 int duration = 1000;
 Future<bool> willPop() async{
    int now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
     if(back && time >= now){
         back = false;
         exit(0);
      }else{
         time =  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch+ duration;
         print("again tap");
         back = true;
         ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Press again the button to exit")));
      }
      return false;
 }

 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: onWill,
  child: Scaffold()
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a snackbar you should provide a scaffold key as it's related to a scaffold, so this key should make the trick of calling a snackbar outside of it's scaffold parent.

Here is a solution :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async{
        DateTime initTime = DateTime.now();
        popped +=1;
        if(popped>=2) return true;
        await _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
            content: Text('Tap one more time to exit.',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        )).closed;

        // if timer is > 2 seconds reset popped counter
        if(DateTime.now().difference(initTime)>=Duration(seconds: 2)) {
        popped = 0;
        }
        return false;
        },
    child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(title : Text("Demo")),
        body: Text("body")
    );
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, you can change backPressTotal value to the number of pressed you want!

```dart
int backPressCounter = 0;
int backPressTotal = 2;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: WillPopScope(child: getBody(), onWillPop: onWillPop),
  );
}

Future<bool> onWillPop() {
    if (backPressCounter < 2) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Press ${backPressTotal - backPressCounter} time to exit app");
      backPressCounter++;
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 500), () {
        backPressCounter--;
      });
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is that the user presses only twice, you can use the first solution of course.
If you want to increase the number of times you click, you can use this solution. Where the user has to press 3 times within two seconds so he can get out

```
  DateTime currentBackPressTime;
  /// init counter of clicks
  int pressCount=1;
```

then :

```
Future<bool> onWillPop() async {

  DateTime now = DateTime.now();



/// here I check if number of clicks equal 3
if(pressCount!=3){

  ///should be assigned at the first click.
  if(pressCount ==1 )
    currentBackPressTime = now;
  pressCount+=1;


  return Future.value(false);
  }else{
  if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
      now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2)) {


    currentBackPressTime = now;
    pressCount=0;

  
    return Future.value(false);
  }
 }


 return Future.value(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime BackPressTime = DateTime.now();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
child: Home(),
onWillPop: exiteApp,
      ),
);
  }
Future<bool> exiteApp() {
    print("exite app");
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    if(now.difference(BackPressTime)< Duration(seconds: 2)){
      return Future(() => true);
    }
    else{
      BackPressTime = DateTime.now();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Press agin");
      return Future(()=> false);
    }
  }
```