How to show alert while pressing home and recent button before exiting the app in flutter Android app
What i need is that when user clicking on home and recent button first alert must come "do you want to exit the app" then again tapping once more app must be closed
i tried using app life cycle but not working properly

Fortunately you can't do this. Showing an alert to a user trying to navigate away from your app would be obnoxious anyway, not sure why you'd want to do this.

did you check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77508483/22282531

@dominicoder---actually  am trying to do a quiz app where user enter to the quiz area these button's should not be used or action must be restricted. if they want to exit there is other button to exit from quiz

You can do it using PopScope. Where you can prevent system back gestures using canPop.
you can also use onPopInvoked parameter if you want.
To use PopScope just wrap your Widget with it and show AlertDialog:
PopScope(
     canPop: false,
     onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {},
     child: TextButton(),
),

For more information about PopScope you can check documentation here: PopScope

popscope only works for back button. Its not working for home and recent buttons
